# Maildev port:1080 not found

Tags: java, email

I have installed maildev via node with `npm install -g maildev` and it's telling me that "MailDev webapp running at [http://0.0.0.0:1080"](http://0.0.0.0:1080%22) but when I go to port 1080 on chrome it just tells me that the site isn't found `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`. I have a backend app javamailsender that i would like to test with maildev and in my `.yml` properties i have:

```
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 1025
    username: hello
    password: hello

    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          ssl:
            trust: "*"
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
          connectiontimeout: 5000
          timeout: 3000
          writetimeout: 5000
```

Comment: The problem isn't the port, it's the IP address. Use `localhost` instead.

Comment: You have helped me 2 times nowi thank you good sir. @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-